# Why does my program's performance increase after the number of threads exceeds the number of cores?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

As part of a white paper I'm doing for a class, I've decided to build a simple program that simulates distributing a 20-second parallelizable task across a given number of threads:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> // for the ctime function.
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "How many threads?";
   int threadCount;
   cin >> threadCount;
   time_t baseTime;
   time(&baseTime);
   #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threadCount)
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
      int timeElapsed = 0;
      time_t currentTime;
      time(&currentTime);
      while (timeElapsed < 2)
      {
         time_t newTime;
         time(&newTime);
         timeElapsed = newTime - currentTime;
      }
   }
   time_t currentTime;
   time(&currentTime);
   cout << currentTime - baseTime;
}
```

The machine I'm running is a Linux machine that uses 4 cores, with one thread per core, so the indicated time elapsed should max out at 4 cores. But it doesn't:

[image: graph]

Something similar happens when I use pthreads. Why is this happening?

Comment: There could be many reasons. Maybe you have hyper threading enabled so your 4 cores can actually handle 8 threads (at reduced perf, but better than 4 threads). Maybe each of your threads often stall and do nothing so other threads can use that time to make progress. Could be a million different reasons.

Comment: Note that nothing happens in the `while (timeElapsed < 2)` loop, so nothing happens in the `for (int i=0; i<10; i++)`. Clearly not what you're seeing here, but a compiler would be justified in removing the time-waster loops completely.

Comment: Obligatory question: are you building your code with compiler optimizations enabled? If not, do so.

Comment: @user4581301: Except that I didn't run the compiler with optimizations.

Comment: You are not doing a fixed amount of work, you are doing work for a fixed amount of time _whether or not that thread is running_. Do you see the issue now? Whether or not your thread is scheduled doesn't make a difference. As long as the thread starts, and is eventually scheduled sometime near its end counter, it still counts as "work" in  your scheme. If you actually did some CPU intensive work (like mine a bitcoin or whatever) you'd see little performance increase after 4.

Comment: @MontanaBurr If you didn't even enable compiler optimizations then why are you bothering to benchmark anything in the first place? Benchmarking unoptimized debug builds of C++ programs is rather pointless and will never be indicative of real-life optimized performance. Don't waste your time benchmarking unoptimized builds. Debug builds are *slow* and the things that are slow often evaporate completely once optimizations are turned on. You cannot learn anything about performance from debug builds.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: You bring up a good point. However, the object is to simulate a task that takes 20-seconds, and my program wastes time because that is the simplest way to simulate the task. Honest question, though - would you propose any alternative ways to simulate it?

Comment: @MontanaBurr There are other, more realistic, ways to make things take ~20sec - for example; do some actual calculations that take roughly that amount of time and cannot be reduced to a constant by the compiler at compile time (by making it depend on user input or current time or similar). And then build your code with optimizations enabled, when benchmarking, *always*.

Comment: It sounds like you assume a spinning thread can't be preempted. That isn't the case, a thread can be suspended at almost any time. In addition, due to the as-if rule, you should not assume the loop will actually exist at run time because it has no observable behavior. Changes to delays and timing are not part of the observable behavior and can be changed by the compiler.

Comment: I just compiled the same code with g++ -O3. So far, I'm getting similar results.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: OK, but how does preemption help speed up the program?

Comment: @MontanaBurr You can only run as many `time(&currentTime);` concurrently as you have concurrent threads. And your code's total expected duration is about 2 seconds after the last call to `time(&currentTime);`. When you have as many threads as loop iterations, non of the calls to `time(&currentTime);` necessarily has to wait for anything else. And that is true even if you had a single CPU core. If the thread happens to be preempted right after each `time(&currentTime);` it can be replaced with another that starts the next iteration right away. This assumes the compiler doesn't remove the loop.

Comment: @MontanaBurr Another wait of putting it is your inner loop waits 2 seconds but that wait still measures the time during which the thread is suspended. If a thread is preempted after `time(&currentTime);` it doesn't matter whether or not it is suspended for those 2 seconds.

Comment: @FrançoisAndriex: And, this thread preemption is why it takes less overall time to run the same task with 10 threads, as opposed to 1?

Comment: @MontanaBurr It makes it possible. It may or may not actually run faster.

Answer (score 4):

Your each "task" is to waste time for about 2 seconds, regardless of the amount of works.

With modern OS (including Linux), the OS switches between threads in a short amount of time, so one CPU core can run multiple threads concurrently.

In this case, the total time to be taken is determined by how many tasks are processed concurrently. (Whether the processing are parallel (run on different cores) is irrevant because the amount of time will not be reflected to the time to take).

Then, the processing will be like:

1 thread

```
1: ABCDEFGHIJ
```

2 threads

```
1: ABCDE
2: FGHIJ
```

3 threads

```
1: ABCD
2: EFG
3: HIJ
```

4 threads

```
1: ABC
2: DEF
3: GH
4: IJ
```

5 threads

```
1: AB
2: CD
3: EF
4: GH
5: IJ
```

6 threads

```
1: AB
2: CD
3: EF
4: GH
5: I
6: J
```

...

9 threads

```
1: AB
2: C
3: D
4: E
5: F
6: G
7: H
8: I
9: J
```

10 threads

```
 1: A
 2: B
 3: C
 4: D
 5: E
 6: F
 7: G
 8: H
 9: I
10: J
```

As you see, using 1 to 5 threads, the minimum number of tasks to be processed by one threads is getting lower when the number of threads increases.

The mimimum don't change using 5 to 9 threads, and decrease again when 10 threads are used.

This explains your graph.

Comment: Does concurrency decrease the overall amount of time taken?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the task is I/O bound?